# Faster RCNN loss Nan from the beginning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, faster-rcnn

I'm using Pytorch with Faster RCNN on dataset having 2 classes and about 100 images for training and 35 for validation in a multi node and multi gpu environment. Just to simplify the debugging, I'm running on a single GPU for the moment, and batch size=1.
The problem is the losses from training is Nan from the beginning, also using other learning rate values. My dataset has COCO format. I checked the training annotations and are ok.

The following my setup:

```
train_dataset = CustomCOCODataset(root_dir=train_image_folder, annotations_file=train_annotations_file, transforms=transform)
val_dataset =  CustomCOCODataset(root_dir=val_image_folder, annotations_file=val_annotations_file, transforms=transfor

train_sampler = DistributedSampler(train_dataset)
val_sampler = DistributedSampler(val_dataset)

batch_size = 1
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=(train_sampler is None), sampler=train_sampler)
val_dataloader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=(val_sampler is None), sampler=val_sampler))
    
num_train_batches = len(train_dataloader)
num_val_batches = len(val_dataloader)
num_classes=3 #cat dogs

model = fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained_backbone=True, num_classes=num_classes)
model = model.to(local_rank)
model = torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(model, device_ids=[local_rank])
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.0005)
```

My training and validation loop:

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, (images, targets) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        images = [image.to(local_rank) for image in images]
            
        targets = [{k: v.to(local_rank) for k, v in t.items()} for t in targets]

        loss_dict = model(images, targets)
        losses = sum(loss for loss in loss_dict.values())
        
        losses.backward()  # Calcolare i gradienti, qua viene fatto il broadcast tra i gradienti
        
        optimizer.step()  # Aggiornare i pesi del modello

        running_loss += losses.item()
  
    print(f"Epoch: {epoch} Loss: {running_loss / (i + 1)}")

    cpu_device = torch.device("cpu")
    model.eval()
    target = []
    preds = []
    metric_summary = {}

    for i, (images, targets) in enumerate(val_dataloader):

        images = [image.to(local_rank) for image in images]
    
        with torch.no_grad():
            outputs = model(images)

        #Skip no predictions
        if outputs[0]['boxes'].numel() == 0:
           continue

        #####################################
        for i in range(len(images)):
            true_dict = dict()
            preds_dict = dict()
            true_dict['boxes'] = targets[i]['boxes'].detach().cpu()
            true_dict['labels'] = targets[i]['labels'].detach().cpu()
            preds_dict['boxes'] = outputs[i]['boxes'].detach().cpu()
            preds_dict['scores'] = outputs[i]['scores'].detach().cpu()
            preds_dict['labels'] = outputs[i]['labels'].detach().cpu()
            preds.append(preds_dict)
            target.append(true_dict)
            #####################################

        metric = MeanAveragePrecision()

        # Copia preds e target sulla GPU
        for i in range(len(preds)):
            for key in preds[i]:
                preds[i][key] = preds[i][key].to(local_rank)  # "device" dovrebbe essere la GPU corretta
            for key in target[i]:
                target[i][key] = target[i][key].to(local_rank)

        metric.update(preds, target)
        metric_summary = metric.compute()

    if 'map' in metric_summary:
        print(f"Epoch: {epoch} Metric summary: {metric_summary['map']}")

    if global_rank == 0 :
        orch.save(model.module.state_dict(), f'modello_salvato_cat_dog_epoch_{epoch+1}.pth')
        rint("Modello salvato!")
```

I did a CustomCocoDataset class, where in get_item i convert boxes as:

```
torchvision.ops.box_convert(torch.tensor(annotation['bbox']), in_fmt="xywh", out_fmt="xyxy")
```

Such conversion should be correct, since I start from COCO dataset where the bbox format is xywh.

The following my complete Custom class:

```
class CustomCOCODataset(Dataset):
def __init__(self, root_dir, annotations_file, transforms=None):
    self.root_dir = root_dir
    self.transforms = transforms
    self.coco = COCO(annotations_file)
    self.image_ids = list(self.coco.imgs.keys())
    self.image_ids = self.filter_empty_images() 
    self.log_annot_issue_x = True
    self.log_annot_issue_y = True
    self.square_training = False
    self.img_size = 640 #detto il default

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.image_ids)

def filter_empty_images(self):
    # Filtra le immagini senza annotazioni
    valid_image_ids = []
    for img_id in self.image_ids:
        annotation_ids = self.coco.getAnnIds(imgIds=img_id)
        annotations = self.coco.loadAnns(annotation_ids)
        if annotations:
            valid_image_ids.append(img_id)
    return valid_image_ids 

def load_image_and_annotations(self, index):
    img_id = self.image_ids[index]
    img_info = self.coco.loadImgs(img_id)[0]
    img_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, img_info['file_name'])
    image = cv2.imread(img_path)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB).astype(np.float32)
    annotation_ids = self.coco.getAnnIds(imgIds=img_info['id'])

    # Ottieni tutte le annotazioni per questa immagine
    annotations = self.coco.loadAnns(annotation_ids)

    boxes = []
    orig_boxes = []
    labels = []
    image_width = image.shape[1]
    image_height = image.shape[0]


    for annotation in annotations:
        # Estrai le coordinate della bounding box
        xmin = annotation['bbox'][0]
        ymin = annotation['bbox'][1]
        xmax = annotation['bbox'][2]
        ymax = annotation['bbox'][3]

        orig_boxes.append([xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax])
        
        xmax_final = xmax
        ymin_final = ymin
        ymax_final = ymax

        boxes.append([xmin_final, ymin_final, xmax_final, ymax_final])

    return image, annotations

def __getitem__(self, idx):
      
    image, annotations = self.load_image_and_annotations(idx)
    #print("idx: ", idx, "image_size: ", image.size)
   
    if self.transforms:
        image = self.transforms(image)

    target_list = []
            
    target = {
        'boxes': [],
        'labels': [],
        'area': [],
        'iscrowd': []
    }

    image_id = torch.tensor([idx])

    for annotation in annotations:
        target = {
            'image_id' : image_id,
            'boxes': torchvision.ops.box_convert(torch.tensor(annotation['bbox']), in_fmt="xywh", out_fmt="xyxy"),
            'labels' : torch.tensor(annotation['category_id']),
            'area': torch.tensor(annotation['area']),
            'iscrowd': torch.tensor(annotation['iscrowd'])
    }
    target_list.append(target)    

    return image, target_list
```

Why does this happen and how to resolve it?